# Retry a maximum of 10 times scp command until it succeeds

Tags: scp, error-handling, syntax

I wish to retry `scp` 10 times and print an error message if it failed.

Below is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE=$1;
echo $FILE;

HOMEDIR="/home/ibro";
tries=0;
while (system "scp -P 3337 $FILE ibrahimince\@localhost:$HOMEDIR/Printed/")
do
    last if $tries++ > 10;
    sleep 3;
done

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
echo "SCP was successful"
else
echo " SCP failed"
fi
```

Unfortunately, I get the below error:

```
npm-debug.log
./test.sh: line 8: system: command not found
```

Below Is detailed output upon @roaima's suggestion

```
$ shellcheck myscript
 
Line 3:
echo $FILE;
     ^-- SC2086: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.

Did you mean: (apply this, apply all SC2086)
echo "$FILE";
 
Line 9:
    last if $tries++ > 10;
                     ^-- SC2210: This is a file redirection. Was it supposed to be a comparison or fd operation?

$
```

Can you please help correct the code?

Comment: What shell did you write this for? Where is your initial first line `#!` marker to identify the interpreter? Please paste it into https://shellcheck.net/ to find obvious errors

Comment: I have updated the original post.

Comment: To my knowledge, bash doesn't have a `system` command, and none is needed: Just put the command directly after `while` (no parenthesis), but don't forget to negate the condition (commands return `0` on "good" outcomes).

Comment: Please paste your code into http://shellcheck.net/ to find obvious errors. Fix those, or ask about them here

Comment: @roaima @dirkt i updated the original post with `shellcheck.net` debug output.

Comment: The shellcheck output isn't for me, it's for you to fix your code. You can then update your question and ask about specific issues that you yourself can't fix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change whatever parameters you want or make a new variable for the file.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Trap interrupts and exit instead of continuing the loop
trap "echo Exited!; exit;" SIGINT SIGTERM

MAX_RETRIES=10
i=0

# Set the initial return value to failure
false

while [ $? -ne 0 -a $i -lt $MAX_RETRIES ]
do
 i=$(($i+1))
 scp -P 3337 my_local_file.txt user@host:/remote_dir/
done

if [ $i -eq $MAX_RETRIES ]
then
  echo "Hit maximum number of retries, ending."
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

The `retry` tool will do this. As requested, we try 10 times before giving up.

By default, we retry forever.

```
~$ retry --times 10 -- scp -P 3337 $FILE ibrahimince@localhost:$HOMEDIR/Printed/
ssh: connect to host localhost port 3337: Connection refused
scp: Connection closed
retry: scp returned 255, backing off for 10 seconds and trying again...
ssh: connect to host localhost port 3337: Connection refused
scp: Connection closed
retry: scp returned 255, backing off for 10 seconds and trying again...
ssh: connect to host localhost port 3337: Connection refused
scp: Connection closed
retry: scp returned 255, backing off for 10 seconds and trying again...
ssh: connect to host localhost port 3337: Connection refused
scp: Connection closed
retry: scp returned 255, backing off for 10 seconds and trying again...
ssh: connect to host localhost port 3337: Connection refused
scp: Connection closed
retry: scp returned 255, backing off for 10 seconds and trying again...
ssh: connect to host localhost port 3337: Connection refused
scp: Connection closed
retry: scp returned 255, backing off for 10 seconds and trying again...
ssh: connect to host localhost port 3337: Connection refused
scp: Connection closed
retry: scp returned 255, backing off for 10 seconds and trying again...
ssh: connect to host localhost port 3337: Connection refused
scp: Connection closed
retry: scp returned 255, backing off for 10 seconds and trying again...
ssh: connect to host localhost port 3337: Connection refused
scp: Connection closed
retry: scp returned 255, backing off for 10 seconds and trying again...
ssh: connect to host localhost port 3337: Connection refused
scp: Connection closed
retry: scp returned 255, backing off for 10 seconds and trying again...
~$
```

https://github.com/minfrin/retry

Available out the box in recent Debian, Ubuntu, and Nix.

(Disclaimer, I am the original author of this tool)